# Borders sticking out of the top bar

Tags: css, border

The following is my code. My questions are below that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My BBC News Reader</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin:0;
        font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    #topbar {
        background-color:#7A0000;
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        color:white;
    }

    .fixedwidth {
        width:1050px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #logodiv {
        padding-top:5px;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #990000;
        padding-right:10px;
    }

    #signindiv {
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:0.9em;
        padding: 6px 80px 12px 20px;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #990000;
    }

    #signindiv img {
        position:relative;
        top:3px;
    }

    #topmenudiv {
        float:left;
    }

    #topmenudiv ul {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    #topmenudiv li {
        list-style:none;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:0.9em;
        border-right:1px solid #990000;
        height:100%;
        padding:10px 20px 12px 20px; 
        float:left;
    }

    #searchdiv {
        padding:5px 0 0 10px;
        float:left;

    }

    #searchdiv input {
        height:25px;
        border:none;
        padding-left:10px;
        background-image:url("images/glass.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:right center;
    }


    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="topbar">

            <div class="fixedwidth">

                <div id="logodiv">

                    <img src="images/bbclogo.png"/>

                </div>

                <div id="signindiv">

                    <p><img src="images/signin.png" width="18px" height="18px"/>Sign    in</p>

                </div>

                <div id="topmenudiv">

                    <ul>
                        <li>News</li>
                        <li>Sport</li>
                        <li>Weather</li>
                        <li>iPlayer</li>
                        <li>TV</li>
                        <li>Radio</li>
                        <li>More...</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div id="searchdiv">

                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to show, I uploaded the code here - http://www.mazdoor.net/bbcnews.html . I will remove once I fix the issue. 
1. The vertical border lines are sticking out. I can't figure out what the issue is. 
2. The Sign in logo and text are not aligning with the BBC logo.

Kindly help me. I just started HTML and CSS 4 days ago.

Thank you

Comment: You didn't say how you wanted things to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
#topmenudiv li{
  height: 100%; <!--- remove
}

#signindiv p{
  margin:0; <!--- remove default margin given by browser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the padding is set on the list items.

Try this:

```
#topmenudiv li {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-right: 1px solid #990000;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

This will remove the height on the padding and set the vertical height of the text with [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My BBC News Reader</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin:0;
        font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    #topbar {
        background-color:#7A0000;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        color:white;
    }

    .fixedwidth {
        width:1050px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #logodiv {
        padding-top:15px;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #990000;
        padding-right:10px;
        min-height: 53px;
    }

    #signindiv {
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:0.9em;
        padding: 6px 80px 12px 20px;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #990000;
    }

    #signindiv img {
        position:relative;
        top:3px;
    }

    #topmenudiv {
        float:left;
    }

    #topmenudiv ul {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    #topmenudiv li {
        list-style:none;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:0.9em;
        border-right:1px solid #990000;
        /*height:100%;*/
        padding:26px 20px; 
        float:left;
    }

    #searchdiv {
        padding:5px 0 0 10px;
        float:left;

    }

    #searchdiv input {
        height:25px;
        border:none;
        padding-left:10px;
        background-image:url("images/glass.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:right center;
    }

    .clear{float:none !important;clear:both;}
    ul li:last-of-type{padding:0px !important;border:none;height:0px !important;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="topbar">

            <div class="fixedwidth">

                <div id="logodiv">
                    <img src="images/bbclogo.png"/>
                </div>

                <div id="signindiv">
                    <p><img src="images/signin.png" width="18px" height="18px"/>Sign    in</p>
                </div>

                <div id="topmenudiv">
                    <ul>
                        <li>News</li>
                        <li>Sport</li>
                        <li>Weather</li>
                        <li>iPlayer</li>
                        <li>TV</li>
                        <li>Radio</li>
                        <li>More...</li>
                        <li class='clear'></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="searchdiv">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
                </div>

                <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in here all the things what have i done is hard to explain i explained it briefly.study the code...and try to understand

1.`<li class='clear'></li>` add for clear floats in ul
`<div class='clear'></div>` add for clear floats fixedwidth div

change topbar div height to auto to get the topbar height according to its inside content.

`#topmenudiv li` padding changes `padding: 26px 20px` then its height will equal with signindiv height.

delete #topmenudiv li height then   `#topmenudiv li` height will be height auto.( if `#topmenudiv li{height:auto;}` list items get full screen heigh)

2.
to align logos vertically simply add padding top value to logodiv.you have to use your eye sight to check whether is it align with signout logo or not.